# Async or Lazy logging in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I've implemented logging in django. Logs are written into files. I want the process of logging to be asynchronous or lazy as I don't want the process of logging and writing to files be the part of main execution cycle (request and response cycle). I've come across options of using celery or queuing methods to achieve this, wondering if there are other solutions or existing libraries for this.